# If 'decltype' is static, why then the ternary operator works in template's trailing return type?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

In Josuttis book I've got this example:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto max (T1 a, T2 b) -> decltype(b<a?a:b)
{
    return b<a?a:b;
}
```

But the

```
b<a
```

part belongs to runtime, right? 
So why do we compare it in the **decltype** (to figure out the static type during the template instantiation)? 
And how does it work properly in compile time?

Comment: Every expression has a type known statically. (This fact is sometimes expressed as "C++ is a statically typed language"). This type depends on the operation being performed and the types of the operands, but not on their values (otherwise it would not be statically known). The ternary expression is no exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that you think `decltype(b<a?a:b)` produces either the type of `a` or `b`, depending on the runtime values. It doesn't, it produces their common type.

Comment: But how exactly did you know it? Why it produces their common type? Is it some special rule? Does it belong to the ternary operator's rules of type deduction ?

Comment: @barney: There indeed is a special rules (actually, set of rules) that determine the type of the `?:` expression. In fact, such rules exist for all expressions.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other details the (very complicated) rules

Comment: @JamesPicone oh I see, thanks, that does make sense... C++ is full of hidden rules... sometimes it appearts just a bit illogical, without knowing them. So If you know the rules you can explain implicit assumptions behind the every piece of code

Comment: @barney: Absolutely. Note that the Java guys really messed up their equivalent set of rules for the ternary conditional operator (they have the reference / primitive issue to deal with)! Us C++ programmers are smarter.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed `b < a` is a runtime concern, but given that C++ is *statically typed*, the *type* of the expression `b < a ? a : b` is known at compile-time when the template is instantitated.

That's what `decltype` is relying upon: `decltype(b < a ? a : b)` is evaluated at compile time and is the common type of `a` and `b`. In this respect `decltype` is similar to `sizeof`.

---

I wonder why the book has the parameters passed by value? This, and along with the fact that named return value optimisation cannot be used since `a` and `b` are function parameters (rule since C++17), seems an expensive way of implementing a `max`, although it doesn't suffer from the pitfalls of returning a `const &` like the C++ standard library version does. I've never come across the book but this seems to be an indication of it being rather poor quality.

Comment: But why the compiler decides that `b<a ? a : b` should produce the common type? Is it a hidden rule that belongs to the ternary operator?

Comment: @barney: It's not a hidden rule insofar that the standard enumerates it in detail, but it is complicated. Here's a link: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other

Comment: I think, in this case the book just narrowed the scope of the example to the `decltype`. But anyway C++ is very complicated in details. That's why its almost impossible to learn and understand it indepth without asking "stupid" questions here on Stack. I am wondering is there other way? Like a ultimate book that will answer to all the questions with examples, and step by step. Because so many years and still I'm just got stuck with this simple case.

Comment: @barney: I'm not saying I'm perfect but I came through the K & R, C89 at university, Stroustrup, coding professionally, answering questions on this site, route. That's taught me a lot.

Comment: People starting with C, assumed C++ to be an extension of it. Hence came the first generation of authors who wrote books that no sane pro recommends today. Most university instructors belong to a generation that grew up with that kind of training. Regarding C++ as a distinct language - that supports C primitives as a subset - is a relatively new movement. People start with horror stories in university, and just end up as none-C++ programmers. Once you experience with one tool, other tools start to look wierd or nasty. If one need learn a new language, then he gotta start a patient negotiati

Comment: -on with his other self who starts to complain and constantly criticize

Comment: @Red.Wave Bathsheba That's true, C++ universe is very different, and I agree that people just learn it in the wrong way. And the tradition goes from old C instructors. C++ is strongly typed language with many hidden rules (and opportunities) and 99% of the time it just works "automagically" but you still have to build this insights and "under the hood" understanding, by talking on stack, or answering questions, collecting this "hidden " layer of C++ knowledge and its internal logic. And its awesome. Maybe the new generation of authors will make some other books with proper foundation...

Comment: @barney OT but in short words my point is we need to overcome our mental inertia to conquer new horizons.